# ReactJS render error Uncaught Invariant Violation: ReactDOM.render()

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

having the following react(15.0.2) example

Component

```
import React from 'react';

class Test extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div> Test </div>;
    }
}

export default Test;
```

and trying to render like

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Test from './components/Test';

ReactDOM.render(<Test/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

I do get

`bundle.js:707 Uncaught Invariant Violation: ReactDOM.render(): Invalid component element. Instead of passing a string like 'div', pass React.createElement('div') or <div />`.

and webpack config

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {

    entry: './app/index.js',
    output: {
        path: './app',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port: 3333
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js[x]?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: ['babel'],
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

package.json installed dependencies

```
 "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.11.0",
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "cors": "^2.7.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.16.1",
    "immutable": "^3.8.1",
    "mongoose": "^4.4.15",
    "react": "^15.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-router": "^2.4.0",
    "redux": "^3.5.2",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.10.0"
  }
```

when I do

`webpack --display-error-details` the bundle.js is getting generated

what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: have you installed the presets?

Comment: Is your dev server serding a index.html with an element with an id of `app` in it? I noticed your requiring in `html-webpack-plugin` but not using it (which is to serve an html file)

Comment: html-webpack-plugin is not used I have and index.html in the root of application which contains that id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had your same issue, in my case it was an error in the webpack configuration. Notice that the output path must be specified as an **absolute path** ([See Webpack Doc here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-path)). 
So your output path should be set to something like this:

```js
path.resolve(__dirname, "app"),
```

Double check the result with a console.log to make sure that the path is correctly resolved to the absolute path where you want your output to go to.